# React: populating select option tab from nested data set

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im trying to create a `React functional component` that will populate a select option tags from nested data but having trouble getting it to work.

Here's the working copy of the code at codesandbox:  [sample project](https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-payne-87svh?file=/src/App.js:2582-2970)

My data looks like this:

```
{
  channels: [
    {
      id: "1878",
      name: "Audio/Video",
      depth: 0,
      children: [
        {
          id: "1885",
          name: "Comedy",
          depth: 1,
          children: []
        },
        {
          id: "1886",
          name: "Opera",
          depth: 1,
          children: []
        },
        {
          id: "1894",
          name: "Lifestyle",
          depth: 1,
          children: [
            {
              id: "1895",
              name: "Fashion",
              depth: 2
            },
            {
              id: "1896",
              name: "Fitness",
              depth: 2
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    
    ...
    
  ]
}
```

I created a function that console log the result as I expected. But having trouble translating this to a `React` functional component.

Here's the function that prints to console (output is what I wanted but as option tabs):

```
DeepIteratorTree(json);

function DeepIteratorTree(target) {
  const channels = target.channels;
  // console.log(channels)
  return channels.map((el) => {
    if (el.depth === 0) {
      console.log(el.name);
      if (el.children.length !== 0) {
        el.children.map((ch) => {
          console.log(
            `${" ".repeat(Number.parseInt(ch.depth, 10))}${" "}${ch.name}`
          );
          if (ch.children.length !== 0) {
            ch.children.map((chch) => {
              console.log(
                `${" ".repeat(Number.parseInt(chch.depth, 10))}${" "}${
                  chch.name
                }`
              );
              return null;
            });
          }
          return null;
        });
      }
    }
    return null;
  });
}
```

console out put:

```
Audio/Video 
  Comedy 
  Opera 
  Lifestyle 
   Fashion 
   Fitness 
Reader 
  News 
  Publishing 
   Books 
   Magazines 
Gallery 
  Arts 
Shows
```

Following function works to populate the first level option tags but but not the next level. I have also tried using nested ternary statements but unable to make it work.

```
function DeepIteratorTree2(target) {
  const channels = target.json.channels;

  return channels.map((el) => {
    if (el.depth === 0) {
      return <option key={el.name}>{el.name}</option>;
    }
    if (el.children.length !== 0) {
      return el.children.map((ch) => {
        return <option key={ch.name}>{ch.name}</option>;
      });
    }

    return null;
  });
  // return null
}
```

Thank you in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to deep iterate and `map` DOM Nodes yourself in React, I think you can benefit from **flattening** your `json.channels` array first and then just simply having a single `map` over that **flattened** `channels` array to render **select** options like so :-

```
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const channels = flatten(json.channels);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <select>
        <ChannelsSelector channels={channels} />
      </select>
    </div>
  );
}

const json = {
  channels: [
    {
      id: "1878",
      name: "Audio/Video",
      depth: 0,
      children: [
        {
          id: "1885",
          name: "Comedy",
          depth: 1,
          children: []
        },
        {
          id: "1886",
          name: "Opera",
          depth: 1,
          children: []
        },
        {
          id: "1894",
          name: "Lifestyle",
          depth: 1,
          children: [
            {
              id: "1895",
              name: "Fashion",
              depth: 2
            },
            {
              id: "1896",
              name: "Fitness",
              depth: 2
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: "1879",
      name: "Reader",
      depth: 0,
      children: [
        {
          id: "1902",
          name: "News",
          depth: 1,
          children: []
        },
        {
          id: "1903",
          name: "Publishing",
          depth: 1,
          children: [
            {
              id: "1904",
              name: "Books",
              depth: 2
            },
            {
              id: "1905",
              name: "Magazines",
              depth: 2
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: "1880",
      name: "Gallery",
      depth: 0,
      children: [
        {
          id: "1908",
          name: "Arts",
          depth: 1,
          children: []
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: "1884",
      name: "Shows",
      depth: 0,
      children: []
    }
  ]
};

function flatten(channels) {
  const output = [];

  function process(channels) {
    for (let index = 0; index < channels.length; index++) {
      const channel = channels[index];
      output.push(channel.name);
      if (channel.children && channel.children.length > 0) {
        process(channel.children);
      }
    }
  }
  process(channels);
  return output;
}

function ChannelsSelector({ channels }) {
  return channels.map((channel) => {
    return <option key={channel}>{channel}</option>;
  });
}
```

Here is the forked version :-

[image: Edit condescending-voice-vi4oc]

**Note :- There could be a better *declarative* implementation of `flatten` function. The above has an *imperative* one. Following is a declarative one :-**

```
function flatten(channels) {
  return channels.reduce((output,channel)=>{
    output.push(channel.name);
    if(channel.children?.length>0)
    {
    let children = flatten(channel.children);
    output = output.concat(children)
    // or output.push(...children)
    }
    return output;
  },[])
}
```

Comment: Thanks @lakshya. How would I make it so that output has the nesting as well (parent/child parent/child/child)? Just like how it is outputting to the console? (see output from function DeepIteratorTree(json) )

Comment: I finally decided to use your suggestion and added nesting by multiplying Non-breaking space by depth. (ex: "\u00a0" x depth).

Comment: @Yeah that would work as a workaround. I think a better way would be using a custom component instead of `select` and `option` combo where multi-level options nesting is allowed. Simple HTML `select` and `option` as far as I know doesn't have those sort of customisations except some stuff with `optgroup`

Comment: Yes! I have been think about going the custom component route. It's a battle I have to fight another time. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You are checking

```
el.depth === 0
```

Instead of
`el.children.length === 0`

In this part:

```
return channels.map((el) => {
if (el.depth === 0) {
  return <option key={el.name}>{el.name}</option>;
}
if (el.children.length !== 0) {
  return el.children.map((ch) => {
    return <option key={ch.name}>{ch.name}</option>;
  });
}

return null;
```

});

Working example:
[Working Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-elgamal-1s78p)

Hope that is what your are trying to achieve...

Comment: Hi @michael thanks. But I would like to have the nesting in the output. Like a nested category tree dropdown.